# Beamer and Pause : displaying a picture and in the meantime some text

Tags: beamer, floats

I wrote the following code :

```
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Context} \vspace{+0.05cm}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item Bob \pause
                \item Bob2 \pause
            \end{itemize}
            \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics[scale=0.18]{myPic.jpg} 
            \caption{myPic title}
            \end{figure}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
```

I don't manage to display at first Bob AND in the meantime the entire figure myPic (picture+caption). First of all, using pause make the picture not hidden, and the caption is only read at the 3th step. I also tried to use

```
 onslide<1>
```

for the figure but it didn't worked.

Please also note that I am using :

```
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
```

To sum up, here are the steps I would like to obtain if possible.

> Step 1: Bob and the entire figure (picture+caption) are displayed
>
> Step 2: Step 1 remains on screen + Bob2 is displayed

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: For the edit, change `<1>` to `<1->` before bob

Comment: Thanks I sorted this out in checking the command \only that I didn't know ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have some problems with your code such as `/pause` instead of `\pause`, missing `\end{figure}` etc. When fixed it looks like the code works properly

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{block}{Context} \vspace{+0.05cm}
            \begin{itemize}
                \item<1> Bob
                \item<2> Bob2
            \end{itemize}
            \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \hfill%
    \begin{column}{.48\textwidth}
            \begin{figure}
            \centering
            \includegraphics<1>[scale=0.18]{example-image} 
            \only<1>{\caption{myPic title}}
            \end{figure}
    \end{column}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It's working very fine, I didn't know the fact that you can force the content to be displayed thanks to *<number>* .  I added <1-> or <2-> so that it remains on screen. Thank you for your help!

Comment: You might also provide a `figure`-free version with the help of `\captionof` as there's no point in having a floating environment here.

Comment: @Header12 My pleasure. The whole overlay specification is based on that. Check the manual for lots of other options

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino That's what I used to think, but Gonzalo Medina reminded me that `beamer` changes the meaning of `figure` and `table` environments so they are not floats anymore. But still I think captions are redundant in a presentation.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino & @ percusse : Do you think I shouldn't use "caption" ? Sorry but I am not a pro in presentation making, as you could realise. What should I use instead then ?

Comment: @percusse: oh, that's the new lesson learnt today. :) And I agree with you: the captions are redundant (well under my point of view they just occupy the space useless as one could explain the meaning by voice).

Comment: @Header12: incidentally you already have my opinion while I was answering to percusse :)

Comment: Right ^^, I just thought having these captions make all things clear. I am now waiting the opinion of @percusse

Comment: @Header12 I don't put anything other than the source of the image if necessary. I would be busy talking about it anyway during the presentation :) I have a more controversial answer here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118478/why-are-beamer-subsubsections-evil/118490#118490 :D